# Getting error while run the hyperledger using docker-composer

Tags: docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

actually I am want to step up hyperledger network using fabric CA, however my CA docker get Exited whenever I up the docker-composer.

I found root cause as it happens because "FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE" changing every time however I put it manually.
 " - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE=/var/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server- 
config/bac7a78da8de5b5071c62cefa3ada1c978dadcce333cb92b5ea9e7c3462ca477_sk". In that variable fact is

> "bac7a78da8de5b5071c62cefa3ada1c978dadcce333cb92b5ea9e7c3462ca477_sk"

How can I make it fixed with some variable ID in docker-composer file

```
My docker-composer-file

        version: '2'

networks:
  dfarm:


services:
#ca 
  ca.dfarmadmin.com:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/var/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca.dfarmadmin.com
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_CERTFILE=/var/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/localhost-7054.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE=/var/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/bac7a78da8de5b5071c62cefa3ada1c978dadcce333cb92b5ea9e7c3462ca477_sk
    ports:
      - "7054:7054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw'
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/caserver/admin/msp/cacerts:/var/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
    container_name: ca.dfarmadmin.com
    networks:
      - dfarm


  # Orderer
  orderer.dfarmadmin.com:
    container_name: orderer.dfarmadmin.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:$IMAGE_TAG
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CFG_PATH=/var/hyperledger/config
      # - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOGLEVEL=DEBUG
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=orderer.dfarmadmin.com
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/var/hyperledger/genesis/dfarm-genesis.block
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/var/hyperledger/msp
      - ORDERER_FILELEDGER_LOCATION=/var/ledger
    working_dir: $HOME
    command: orderer
    volumes:
    # Folder with genesis block
    - ${PWD}/config/orderer:/var/hyperledger/genesis
    # Map the folder with MSP for orderer
    - ${PWD}/client/orderer/orderer//msp:/var/hyperledger/msp
    # Map the current folder to cfg
    - ${PWD}/config/orderer:/var/hyperledger/config
    - ${HOME}/ledgers/ca/orderer.dfarmadmin.com:/var/ledger
    ports:
      - 7050:7050
    networks:
      - dfarm

  # Dfarmadmin peer1
  dfarmadmin-peer1.dfarmadmin.com:
    container_name: dfarmadmin-peer1.dfarmadmin.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:$IMAGE_TAG
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CFG_PATH=/var/hyperledger/config
      # - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=debug
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG

      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock

      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_dfarm

      - CORE_PEER_ID=dfarmadmin-peer1.dfarmadmin.com
      # - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=dfarmretail-peer1.dfarmretail.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=dfarmadmin-peer1.dfarmadmin.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=dfarmadmin-peer1.dfarmadmin.com:7051
      # - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7051
      # - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=0.0.0.0:7051

      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=DfarmadminMSP
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/var/hyperledger/msp
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=false
      # - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true
      # - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false
      # - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_FILESYSTEMPATH=/var/ledger
    working_dir: $HOME
    # command: peer node start --peer-chaincodedev=true
    command: peer node start

    volumes:
      # Folder with channel create tx file
      - ${PWD}/config:/var/hyperledger/channeltx
      # Map the folder with MSP for Peer
      - ${PWD}/client/dfarmadmin/peer1/msp:/var/hyperledger/msp
      # Map the current folder to cfg
      - ${PWD}/config:/var/hyperledger/config
      - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
      # Ledger folder for the peer
      - ${HOME}/ledgers/ca/dfarmadmin-peer1.dfarmadmin.com/:/var/ledger
    depends_on: 
      - orderer.dfarmadmin.com
    ports:
      - 7051:7051
      - 7052:7052
      - 7053:7053
    networks:
      - dfarm

  # Dfarmretail peer1
  dfarmretail-peer1.dfarmretail.com:
    container_name: dfarmretail-peer1.dfarmretail.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:$IMAGE_TAG
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CFG_PATH=/var/hyperledger/config
      # - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=debug
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=info

      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock

      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_dfarm

      - CORE_PEER_ID=dfarmretail-peer1.dfarmretail.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=dfarmretail-peer1.dfarmretail.com:8051
      # - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=dfarmretail-peer1.dfarmretail.com:8051
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=dfarmretail-peer1.dfarmretail.com:8051
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=dfarmretail-peer1.dfarmretail.com:8052
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=dfarmretail-peer1.dfarmretail.com:8051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=DfarmretailMSP
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/var/hyperledger/msp
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=false
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb:5984
      # - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true
      # - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false
      # - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_FILESYSTEMPATH=/var/ledger
    working_dir: $HOME
    # command: peer node start --peer-chaincodedev=true
    command: peer node start

    volumes:
      # Folder with channel create tx file
      - ${PWD}/config:/var/hyperledger/channeltx
      # Map the folder with MSP for Peer
      - ${PWD}/client/dfarmretail/peer1/msp:/var/hyperledger/msp
      # Map the current folder to cfg
      - ${PWD}/config:/var/hyperledger/config
      - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
      # Ledger folder for the peer
      - ${HOME}/ledgers/ca/dfarmretail-peer1.dfarmretail.com:/var/ledger
    depends_on: 
      - orderer.dfarmadmin.com
    ports:
      - 8051:8051
      - 8052:8052
      - 8053:8053
    networks:
      - dfarm

  couchdb:
    container_name: couchdb
    image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb
    # Populate the COUCHDB_USER and COUCHDB_PASSWORD to set an admin user and password
    # for CouchDB.  This will prevent CouchDB from operating in an "Admin Party" mode.
    environment:
      - COUCHDB_USER=
      - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=
    ports:
      - 5984:5984
    networks:
      - dfarm


  cli:
    container_name: cli
    image: hyperledger/fabric-tools
    tty: true
    environment:
      - GOPATH=/opt/gopath
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=info
      - CORE_PEER_ID=cli
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=dfarmadmin-peer1.dfarmadmin.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=DfarmadminMSP
      #- CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/ 
peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.exampl 
      e.com/msp
      -  CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/var/hyperledger/msp
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_KEEPALIVE=10
    working_dir:  $HOME
    command: /bin/bash
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./../chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/
        - ./crypto- 

    config:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/
    networks:
        - dfarm
    depends_on:
     - orderer.example.com
     - peer0.org1.example.com
     - couchdb
```

Comment: See byfn.sh of first-network from fabric-samples. You can use a script to update that file name dynamically.

Comment: could you please elaborate what mean of "a script to update that file name dynamically."

Answer (score 0):

there is a file called docker-template.yaml file in fabric samples/firstnetwork/ . Check it. So one template file acts a backup and one docker-composer.yaml file gets updated with new certificates.If you still face error, let me know I can help you from this